# How to create links to sections in pdf

Tags: html, css, pdf, anchor

Can we create a hyperlink or an embed tag that will display a specified page/section of a PDF document?

let me know if anybody has any idea

ex:
Open PDF using subsection

Comment: Do you mean like a contents page?

Comment: when i click on the anchor tag i need to open the particular section in a pdf file

Comment: <a href="pdffile.pdf">Click to view pdf file</a>.. @ kumar: do u want like this?

Comment: @Indian: no i need like this <a href="pdfile.pdf#subsection.2.3" /> here 2.3 is a section in the table of contents of pdfile when i click on this anchor tag i need to go to particular section which i was mentioned in the anchor tag

Comment: Do you need a solution supporting all browsers with pdf plug ins or integrated PDF viewers?

Answer (score 6):

I know appending `#page=X` works, but I've now had some luck appending `#subsection.X.Y`. For example: http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#subsection.14.1

Comment: How are subsections identified?

Comment: Using your link I end up slightly below section 14.1, i.e. I cant see the section heading. This is different from using the links contained in the table of contents of the document, which places me right where I would expect to be. Any Idea why this is the case?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm using Chromium, and see the same effects as you. It might be browser-specific. With Firefox it doesn't work at all, becoming simply `file:///tmp/mozilla_username0/beameruserguide.pdf` (the subsection part of the URL is removed).

Answer (score 0):

Just to go to an existing PDF file page you can use

```
#page=pageNumber
```

PDF parameter.

Yes it seems to be possible, please see this link http://www.pdfobject.com/examples/index.php and http://www.pdfobject.com/ for more information. This is from the site *"PDFObject is an easy-to-use method for dynamically embedding PDF files into HTML documents. It uses JavaScript to generate and inject a standards-friendly  "*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function (){
  var success = new PDFObject({ url: "http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe  
   /en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters_v9.pdf#page=6&zoom=150,0,216" 
  }).embed("pdf");

};

</script>
```

As you can see you can change the URL link to

```
thefile.pdf#page=YOURDESIREDPAGE
```

Linking to a destination within PDF in a webpage as found on [this page](http://www.planetpdf.com/enterprise/article.asp?ContentID=6426),
Citation start:
**"**

```
Linking to a destination is essentially the same principle but involves a few more   
steps 
and setting up. First up, you'll need to create the destination.

Creating a destination in a PDF using Adobe Acrobat:

Manually navigate through the PDF for the desired location, and magnification.
Move your curser to the right of the PDF, in the navigation pane.
Right click and select destination. This will open the Destinations pane.
Right click, select New Destination enter an appropriate name and select the area that  
you want the destination to link to.

NOTE: Make sure that the name does not have any spaces as it makes it easier to link to 
afterwards.

You are now ready to link to the destination using a similar syntax as linking to a
specific page, instead of #page write #nameddest.
Append "#nameddest=" and the name of your chosen destination. So, if your PDF has a    
named destination, "TOC", that points to a table of contents, then your link code will 
look like this:

<a href="http://www.mydomain.com/myPDF.pdf#nameddest=TOC">Link Text</a>
```

**"**

Comment: @54N1L without using this javascript can i make use of adobe parameters

Comment: Yes but it wouldn’t be embedded in the page then right? Just take an URL to a PDF document on the internet and test it out. Add the #page="a existing number here"

Comment: <a href="pdfile.pdf#page=6" /> it is working fine for some pdf.i am converted the word document file to .pdf file using microsoft office 2007.in this case i am using #page=6 then it is working fine.if i want to a specfic sub section instead of page number of the pdf then it is not working

Comment: If you are using word then create hyperlinks or create a contents page. Once converted to pdf it'll keep the links intact